# Unaccent function return 1

Tags: php

I'm trying to use unaccent function to remvoe special characters.

If put: echo Unaccent('áéç'); results are ok

When i try to add a exploded parameter:  echo Unaccent($foo[1]); results is 1

Any suggestion?

```
$fiche = file('fiches.txt');
foreach ($fiche as $line_num => $line) {
echo $line;

$foo = explode (",", $line);

function Unaccent($string)
{
return preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
}

echo Unaccent($foo[1]);
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug this?  What does `var_dump($foo[1]);` show?

Comment: Where is the close `}` for your `foreach` loop?  Are you (re-)declaring `Unaccent` inside the loop?

Comment: } is closed
var_dump retur this: string(9) " ACaÇçÇÃÕ"

Comment: This works fine at my end (PHP 5.4.4): `$foo = explode(',', 'test,tésîøit'); echo Unaccent($foo[1]);`. `preg_replace()` returns `NULL` if no match is found, so that's not the `NULL`. Try `print_r(Unaccent($foo[1]));` and see what it gives back. `echo` is a void-type function so it can't return `TRUE` a.k.a. 1, so it has to be something happening with the input of the function. Or (but highly unlikely) you overwritten the echo function with `override_function()`.

Comment: print_r($foo[1]); return ACaÇçÇÃÕ

print (Unaccent($foo[1])); return nothing

(I'm on php 5.3.1)

Comment: Nothing returned is the `NULL` it returns, meaning no results are found. You should add a check in the function letting it return `FALSE` or something more readable to check.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved in this way:

```
preg_replace("/&([a-z])[a-z]+;/i", "$1", htmlentities($line));
```

Many thanks to all.